# How can I delete twitch message? Single message without timeout. [tmi.js]

Tags: node.js, events, bots, twitch, twitch-api

I want to delete a single message on twitch using `tmi.js` without using timeout on the sender.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete a single message using tmi.js

```
client.deletemessage(TWITCH_CHANNEL, messageObject.id);
```

See [TMI.js #deleteMessage](https://d-fischer.github.io/twitch-chat-client/reference/classes/ChatClient.html#deleteMessage)

Answer (score -3):

You're not able to remove a single message in chat without timing them out when using tmi.js extension, you can only clear the chat fully using `client.clear("channel");` or you can timeout a person for one second to get rid of all the messages specifically  using  `client.timeout("channel", "username", 1, "reason");` I'd recommend reading the documentation for the tmi.js extension at https://github.com/tmijs/docs which will give you all the details on commands and configuration.